# Let $A_1,A_2,..,A_n$ be the vertices of n sides of a regular polygon such that $1/A_1.1/A_2=1/A_1.1/A_3+1/A_1.1/A_4$ then value of $n$ must be?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Let $A_1,A_2,..,A_n$ be the vertices of n sides of a regular polygon such that $$\frac{1}{A_1A_2}=\frac{1}{A_1A_3}+\frac{1}{A_1A_4}$$ then value of $n$ must be?

Any ideas on how to start?
I'm having a feeling that this has something to do with n th roots of unity.

Comment: It looks like you got a bunch of exercises about roots of unity and you decided to let MSE solve them for you. I do not think this is the correct approach, neither for you or for the MSE community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** You're on the right track. Consider the $n$-sided polygon with center at $(0,0)$ and each vertex at a distance $1$ from the origin. Then you can easily write the coordinates of the vertices and the distances in terms of $n$.

Comment: Yes, finally that'll lead you to solve a trigonometric equation to get the value of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Ptolemy's theorem in the cyclic quadrilateral $A_1A_3A_4A_5$ and deduce that $A_1A_4=A_1A_5$ so n must be 7.